# Why are my DHCP leases not working?

Tags: networking, dhcp, troubleshooting, ip-address

I am trying to make DHCP assign an IP address to the "PCNEW" node, but it is not working. Can anyone explain why?

[image]

Comment: @АнгелХаджиев is this a lab setup? how is the server and client connected? I'm thinking you have have something blocking the request like a router with no ip-helper configured?